# Continuity and differentiability of a function in a point

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function
$f(x) = |x − 2|$ at $x = 2$.

How to prove is not continuous at $2$? And my goal is proving $f (x)$ is not differentiable at $2$.

Comment: It is continuous at $x=2$ but not differentiable.

Comment: why ? I think this is not continuous and not differentiable at 2. And how to prove it?

Comment: @brian: You must be misunderstanding something. If you tell us _why_ you think the functions is not continuous at $2$, it will be easier to help pinpoint what your misunderstanding is.

Comment: For continuity of functions in one variable, drawing the function helps. This might persuade you that the function is continuous at $x = 2$ (and in fact every where else too).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Calculate the limit for $x\downarrow 2$ form above and $x \uparrow 2$ from below and compare these values to $f(x=2)$. If they are equal that the function is contiuous at $x=2$.

For differentiability find the derivative for $x\geq 2$ and $x\leq 2$ and compare them for $x=2$. If both derivatives give the same value and the function is continuous, then your function is differentiable at $x=2$. If they are not the same then the function is not differentiable at $x=2$.

Comment: can I prove this by contradiction. and I suppose f is differentiable first and then show there are two different limit which x>2 and x<2.

Comment: What do you mean by prove? This is just an exercise where you simply check the conditions.

Comment: I am real-analysis student. So my goal is to use either sequence or ϵ δ condition to show my claim.